# Add sound when turning page with the keyboard

Tags: javascript

How to add a turning pages sound effect without to use the Next / Previous buttons, because it also controlled by the keyboard arrows.

Comment: 1. make a function playSoundPage()
2. make a function nextPage(); another previousPage();
3. attach the previous button + keydown event on a function calling playSoundPage() + previousPage(), do the same for next page.

Answer (score 1):

if you attach an event to the left and right arrow (with `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent` methods) this won't destroy your defined handler previously attached.

Just be sure to avoid a syntax like `<rightarrownode>.onclick = function() {}` since this way to will remove all previous handlers.